# IOS: Sending byte data to an embedded device through bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am building an app that connects an iOS device to a smartwatch through bluetooth which returns blood pressure, heart rate, etc.

Once I establish a connection with the watch from an iOS device (using the `CoreBluetooth Framework`), I should be able to complete the handshake with the watch by sending 7 different byte arrays to the watch in succession for which the watch responds back by sending the corresponding byte data.

For example, the first byte array would contain a command to retrieve firmware version of the watch and the watch responds back with its version and so on. The problem is I'm not able to figure out how to send a byte array to the watch once the bluetooth connection is made and by the way, the watch is `BLE 4.0 device`.

I built the same app in android where once a bluetooth connection was made, a bluetooth socket was registered and I got input stream and output stream from this socket.

By using these, I was able to send and retrieve byte data to and from the watch.

Is there anyway to achieve the same in iOS?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's a Bluetooth Low-Energy watch? The handshake you're talking about made me doubt about it.

Comment: @Larme Yes, I'm sure its a Bluetooth Low energy watch. There is nothing mentioned about sending and receiving byte data in the (core bluetooth) framework.

Comment: Because Bluetooth Low-Energy works with Services & Characteristics. Take a look at Apple iOS Sample with Bluetooth Low-Energy. "Classical" Bluetooth & BLE don't work the same way.

Comment: @Larme I had gone through these samples already and realised that they comprise of Services & Characteristics. This watch(METAWATCH MW3005) starts advertising only when the bluetooth handshake is complete.Is there any possible way i could send data initially to the watch?

Comment: That's a really strange approach... Often, you may have to do the pairing before accessing the characteristics, but the approche is quite weird.
Maybe you have access to only one characteristic (in writability) and once you've written what's you need there, it give you access to the others.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The pairing is done first. Then, the handshake must be completed. The hanshake includes following commands:1. Get Version from watch
2. Set Watch Mode to watch
3. Set Patient Info to watch
4. Get Patient Info from watch
5. Get Algo Param from watch
6. Set Event axis to watch
7. Set Current Time to watch.
Each of these command is completed by sending commandcodes to the watch and is done one after the other.

Comment: @Larme forgot to tag you in the previous comment

Comment: You should try on their forums support.